# Консольная программа на C++ с использованием UNICODE

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

Проблема в приведении типов при попытке написать код для WinAPI. Программа простенькая, для вывода таблицы умножения. Минус в том, что программа из учебника 2004 года по C++, возможно с тех пор многое изменилось.
Суть проблемы: возникает конфликт типов. `Ошибка (активно)  E0144   значение типа "const wchar_t *" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "TCHAR *"` также есть такие ошибки типа:

`E0167 аргумент типа "const wchar_t *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPWSTR"` ,

`E0513 значение типа "const wchar_t *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "TCHAR"`,

`C2440 инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "const wchar_t [20]" в "TCHAR *"` Ещё не очень разбираюсь в Венгерской нотации и обозначениях при программировании на Windows, поэтому требуется помощь: "Что исправить, чтобы задумка автора кода работала?". Сам код ниже:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

BOOL PrintMsg(HANDLE hOut, LPCTSTR pMsg);
BOOL PrintStrings(HANDLE hOut, ...);

int main(char argc, char ** _targv) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int k;
    HANDLE hStdOut;
    hStdOut = CreateFile(_T("CONOUT$"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    SetConsoleMode(hStdOut, ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT | ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT);
    TCHAR * pr = _T("Введите множитель: ");
    PrintMsg(hStdOut, pr);
    cin >> k;
    PrintMsg(hStdOut, CharUpper(_T("Таблица умножения:\n")));
    TCHAR str1[3]; _itot(k, str1, 10); str1[2] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        TCHAR str2[3]; _itot(i, str2, 10); str2[2] = 0;
        int d = k * i;
        TCHAR str3[3]; _itot(d, str3, 10); str3[2] = 0;
        TCHAR *st = new TCHAR[25];
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            st[i] = _T("\0");
            st = wcscat(st, str2);
            st = wcscat(st, _T("*"));
            st = wcscat(st, str1);
            st = wcscat(st, _T("="));
            st = wcscat(st, str3);
            st = wcscat(st, _T("\n"));
            PrintMsg(hStdOut, st);
        }
    }
    getch();
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

На самом деле с того времени поменяло совсем не много. А проблема тут очевидно в использовании `T` макросов вместо использования `wchar_t` напрямую. Например

```
 hStdOut = CreateFile(_T("CONOUT$"),
```

должно быть

```
 hStdOut = ::CreateFileW(L"CONOUT$",
```

и т.д.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, везде ниже код должен теперь иметь вид типа:
TCHAR * pr = L"Введите множитель: "; (замена всех _T("") на L"")

Однако ошибка никуда не исчезла(

Comment: @Chudvan Нет, необходимо заменять *все* макросы обратной совместимости на надлежащие типы / функции / литералы.

Comment: Основное, что мешает программе скомпилироваться - проблема в const-ности. При написании const TCHAR * pr = L"Введите множитель: "; - ошибка исчезает, однако не понятно как тогда работать с массивами (TCHAR *st). Например в этой строчке кода: st[i] = L"\0"; ? (Ошибка: E0513 значение типа "const wchar_t *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "TCHAR")

Comment: @Chudvan я же написал, необходимо избавиться от всех макросов совместимомти, чтобы получились правильный типы. т.е. в коде не должно быть `TCHAR`, `LPCTSTR` `CreateFile` `CharUpper` и т.д. Например `TCHAR * pr = L"Введите множитель: ";` должно быть `wchar_t const * const pr = L"Введите множитель: ";` или (вариант для современного с++) `auto const & pr{L"Введите множитель: "};`

Comment: Исправил код немного по-другому, возникла иная ошибка...

Comment: @Chudvan Судя по коду из самоответа вы сделали только хуже.

Comment: Нет, нет)  Я просто не дочитал до конца второй листинг. Там описано тело ф-ии PrintMsg. После описания этой ф-ии всё заработало. Дописал в комментарии ещё часть кода.

Answer (score -2):

Погуглив, исправил код следующим образом:
`#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` - для совместимости с старыми "небезопасными ф-ями". Для возможности изменения строки нужно писать не `TCHAR * pr = _T("Введите множитель: ");`, а `TCHAR pr[] = _T("Введите множитель: ");` (суть в [] - теперь можно инициализировать литералом). Также, вместо `st[i] = _T("\0");` `st[i] = _T('\0');` (символ всё-таки). Новый код:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

BOOL PrintMsg(HANDLE hOut, LPCTSTR pMsg);
BOOL PrintStrings(HANDLE hOut, ...);

int main(char argc, char ** _targv) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int k;
    HANDLE hStdOut;
    hStdOut = CreateFile(_T("CONOUT$"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    SetConsoleMode(hStdOut, ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT | ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT);
    TCHAR pr[] = _T("Введите множитель: ");
    PrintMsg(hStdOut, pr);
    cin >> k;
    TCHAR pr2[] = _T("Таблица умножения:\n");
    PrintMsg(hStdOut, CharUpper(pr2));
    TCHAR str1[3]; _itot(k, str1, 10); str1[2] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        TCHAR str2[3]; _itot(i, str2, 10); str2[2] = 0;
        int d = k * i;
        TCHAR str3[3]; _itot(d, str3, 10); str3[2] = 0;
        TCHAR *st = new TCHAR[25];
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            st[i] = _T('\0');
            st = wcscat(st, str2);
            st = wcscat(st, _T("*"));
            st = wcscat(st, str1);
            st = wcscat(st, _T("="));
            st = wcscat(st, str3);
            st = wcscat(st, _T("\n"));
            PrintMsg(hStdOut, st);
        }
    }
    _getch();
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

В общем, почти все проблемы решены, осталось лишь решить вопрос с новой ошибкой:

```
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "int __cdecl PrintMsg(void *,wchar_t const *)" (?PrintMsg@@YAHPAXPB_W@Z) в функции _main
```

Не подскажите, что тут-то не так?

### РЕШЕНО

Забыл про следующий листинг, где описание ф-ии PrintMsg:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

BOOL PrintStrings(HANDLE hOut, ...) {
    DWORD MsgLen, Count;
    LPCTSTR pMsg;
    va_list pMsgList;
    va_start(pMsgList, hOut);
    while ((pMsg = va_arg(pMsgList, LPCTSTR)) != NULL) {
        MsgLen = lstrlen(pMsg);
        if (!WriteConsole(hOut, pMsg, MsgLen, &Count, NULL)) return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
BOOL PrintMsg(HANDLE hOut, LPCTSTR pMsg) {
    return PrintStrings(hOut, pMsg, NULL);
}

int main(char argc, char ** _targv) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int k;
    HANDLE hStdOut;
    hStdOut = CreateFile(_T("CONOUT$"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    SetConsoleMode(hStdOut, ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT | ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT);
    TCHAR pr[] = _T("Введите множитель: ");
    PrintMsg(hStdOut, pr);
    cin >> k;
    TCHAR pr2[] = _T("Таблица умножения:\n");
    PrintMsg(hStdOut, CharUpper(pr2));
    TCHAR str1[3]; _itot(k, str1, 10); str1[2] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        TCHAR str2[3]; _itot(i, str2, 10); str2[2] = 0;
        int d = k * i;
        TCHAR str3[3]; _itot(d, str3, 10); str3[2] = 0;
        TCHAR *st = new TCHAR[25];
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
            st[j] = _T('\0');
        st = wcscat(st, str2);
        st = wcscat(st, _T("*"));
        st = wcscat(st, str1);
        st = wcscat(st, _T("="));
        st = wcscat(st, str3);
        st = wcscat(st, _T("\n"));
        PrintMsg(hStdOut, st);
    }
    _getch();
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В коде лапша из WCHAR и T-макросов